# Create PDF from WebAPI response

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-web-api

Hey guys hope you're all doing well, well my problem here is that i want to return a PDF file from my WebAPI response, this is the code im using to get the responses to create the pdf file.

```
[Route("Reporte")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> createReport(RequestIdSugeridoModel request)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        ResponseEncabezadoSugeridoModel encabezado = new ResponseEncabezadoSugeridoModel();
        List<ResponseDetalleSugeridoModel> detalle = new List<ResponseDetalleSugeridoModel>();
        SolicitudSugeridoController solicitud;
        Document document;
        System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection CN_SGE = new SqlConnection(CNSGE))
            {
                solicitud = new SolicitudSugeridoController();
                await CN_SGE.OpenAsync();
                await solicitud.GetObtenEncabezadoSugerido(CN_SGE, encabezado, request);
                await solicitud.GetObtenDetSugerido(CN_SGE, detalle, request);
            }

            //start with pdf creation
            document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
            document.AddTitle("Reporte de Compras");
            document.AddCreator("Disisa");
            document.Open();

            // set standard font type and size
            iTextSharp.text.Font _standardFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.HELVETICA, 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);
            //write document header
            document.Add(new Paragraph(encabezado.razonsocial));
            //document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            document.Add(new Paragraph("COMPRAS SUGERIDAS"));
            //document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(encabezado.nombresucursal));
            //document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            // Create table for pdf
            PdfPTable tableHeader = new PdfPTable(2);
            PdfPCell cellFolio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("FOLIO: " + encabezado.folio + " " + "SEMANA: " + encabezado.semana, _standardFont));
            PdfPCell cellFecha = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("FECHA: " + encabezado.fecha, _standardFont));
            // set border and aligment for the cells
            cellFolio.Border = 0;
            cellFolio.HorizontalAlignment = 0; // 0=left, 1=center, 2=right
            cellFecha.Border = 0;
            cellFecha.HorizontalAlignment = 2; // 0=left, 1=center, 2=right
                                               // Add cells to the table header
            tableHeader.AddCell(cellFolio);
            tableHeader.AddCell(cellFecha);

            PdfPTable mainTable = new PdfPTable(8);
            mainTable.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            // here we will add table headers for report details
            PdfPCell cellProducto = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("NOMBRE DEL PRODUCTO", _standardFont));
            PdfPCell cellExistencia = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("EXISTENCIA", _standardFont));
            PdfPCell cellMes1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(encabezado.mes1, _standardFont));
            PdfPCell cellMes2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(encabezado.mes2, _standardFont));
            PdfPCell cellMes3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(encabezado.mes3, _standardFont));
            PdfPCell cellMes4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(encabezado.mes4, _standardFont));
            PdfPCell cellSugerido = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("SUGERIDO", _standardFont));
            PdfPCell cellObservacion = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("OBSERVACIONES", _standardFont));

            mainTable.AddCell(cellProducto);
            mainTable.AddCell(cellExistencia);
            mainTable.AddCell(cellMes1);
            mainTable.AddCell(cellMes2);
            mainTable.AddCell(cellMes3);
            mainTable.AddCell(cellMes4);
            mainTable.AddCell(cellSugerido);
            mainTable.AddCell(cellObservacion);

            foreach (var item in detalle)
            {
                mainTable.AddCell(item.nombreproducto);
                mainTable.AddCell(item.existencia.ToString());
                mainTable.AddCell(item.mes1.ToString());
                mainTable.AddCell(item.mes2.ToString());
                mainTable.AddCell(item.mes3.ToString());
                mainTable.AddCell(item.mes4.ToString());
                mainTable.AddCell(item.sugerido.ToString());
                mainTable.AddCell(item.observacion);
            }

            // Add tableHeader to document
            document.Add(tableHeader);
            // Add mainTable to document
            document.Add(mainTable);

            //return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, document);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream)
                {
                    Headers = {
                        ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Applicat‌​ion.Pdf),
                        ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "PdfFileName.pdf" }
                    }
                }
            };

            // close document and writer
            document.Close();
            writer.Flush();

            return response;
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            ErrorModel _errors = new ErrorModel();
            _errors.message = ex.Message;
            return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, _errors);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorModel _errors = new ErrorModel();
            _errors.message = ex.Message;
            return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, _errors);
        }
    }
```

Right now the only thing i get in my response when im testing it with postman is this:

```
{
"PageNumber": 0,
"LeftMargin": 36,
"RightMargin": 36,
"TopMargin": 36,
"BottomMargin": 36,
"Left": 36,
"Right": 576,
"Top": 756,
"Bottom": 36,
"PageSize": {
    "Type": 30,
    "Chunks": [],
    "Width": 612,
    "Height": 792,
    "Rotation": 0
},
"JavaScript_onLoad": null,
"JavaScript_onUnLoad": null,
"HtmlStyleClass": null
```

}

How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance. I have updated the code the way it is now, with the answer provided by @ckuri

Comment: You would need to return your memory stream, after you reset its position to the beginning. So it should be something like this:

`memoryStream.Position = 0;

HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream)
{
  Headers =
  {
 ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf),
 ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
 {
   FileName = "PdfFileName.pdf"
 }
  }
}
};
return response;`

Comment: @ckuri thanks for the quick answer, its showing an error message that says: Cant get access to a closed secuency. "ExceptionType": "System.ObjectDisposedException".

Comment: The stream mustn't be closed/disposed which will be done either if you call writer.Close or leave the using scope. Therefore you should omit the using (the StreamContent will take care of closing the stream when it's not needed anymore) and replace writer.Close with writer.Flush.

Comment: @ckuri Thanks, i have to move the writer.Flush() before returning the response, and also one more thing, now im not getting any error message, but i get this message: Could not get any response, there was an error connecting to http://localhost:14799/api/ReporteComprasSugerido/Reporte.

Comment: @ckuri I mean im not getting any error message from the code, only the one i told you in the past comment.

Comment: Have you set a request timeout in Postman (see Settings->General) and if so is createReport by chance taking longer than the timeout? I have tried my code just now, and it works for me.

Comment: @ckuri i have updated the code with the answer you gave me, can you take a look at it? Best regards!, and i havent set a timeout in Postman, its with value 0 or infinity.

Comment: document.Close and writer.Flush should go before memoryStream.Position = 0 as otherwise the flushed data would be inserted in the beginning instead of the end and corrupt the steam. Aside from this it looks fine.

Comment: @ckuri Well if i do it the way you tell me, i got an error message: Can't get access to a closed secuency. Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException'

Comment: @ckuri its Cant get access to a closed stream the error message.

Comment: Hi, I recreated your example. Looks like the writer auto-closes the stream. If I put `writer.CloseStream = false;` after `PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);` I get the PDF perfectly fine.

Comment: @ckuri so weird when i test it in my postman i only get a response file that seems to be the pdf but with 0kb. and with the name "response"

Comment: @ckuri thanks a lot man, yeah i was doing something wrong lol, but the only problem i have now is that is not taking the filename, instead it downloads as "response", but now i can see content there.